# Opacity of background-color, but not the text

Tags: css, opacity

How do I make the cross-browser (including Internet Explorer 6) transparency for the background of a `div` while the text remains opaque?

I need to do it without using any library such as jQuery, etc. (But if you know of a library that does it I'd love to know so I can look at their code).

Answer (score 605, accepted):

Use rgba!

```
.alpha60 {
    /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

> In addition to this, you have to declare `background: transparent` for IE web browsers, preferably served via conditional comments or similar!

via http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

Comment: Is there any possibility that IE7 mode in IE9 is different from actual IE7? I'm asking because this code isn't working there. But if we use only three last rules (without `background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);`) - all just fine

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not work in IE8 because IE8 correctly applies the background color. I just took out the fallback for other browsers (which is what, old versions of firefox?). Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508191/ie8-gradient-filter-not-working-if-a-background-color-exists/6300452#6300452

p.s.
@Donotello ie7 mode in ie9 is definitely not is 100% accurate. I use a CMS that requires IE7/8 and the compatibility mode in IE9 breaks all sorts of things in it.

Comment: The linked article says that for IE (version 8, at least), you need to conditionally set `background:transparent` as well.

Answer (score 32):

I use an alpha-transparent PNG for that:

```
div.semi-transparent {
  background: url('semi-transparent.png');
}
```

For IE6, you'd need to use a PNG fix ([1](http://unitinteractive.com/labs/unitpngfix.php), [2](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/)), though.

Comment: Pure CSS > Background Images

Comment: @MarcySutton IMO not always, definitely not. If you look at the answer marked as the answer, you'd understand why. How many hours should we waste for cross-browser compatibility. So, when you absolutely can, (sure, not always) you can use background images. Like I said, JMO.

Comment: The PNG fix 1 is awesome! The accept answer's method does not work on my IE6.

Comment: @Crungmungus there are many JS hacks/polyfills (see links below the code in the answer) and even a [CSS method](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6/) to fix PNG transparency in IE6. Though, in more complex use cases they tend to break one way or another so I've gave up on IE6 PNG transparency several months ago.

Answer (score 16):

I've created that effect on my blog [Landman Code](http://landman-code.blogspot.com/).

What I did was

```css
#Header {
  position: relative;
}
#Header H1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #00FF00;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#Header H2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #FFFF00;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#Header .Background {
  background: #557700;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=30);
  -moz-opacity: 0.30;
  opacity: 0.3;
  zoom: 1;
}
#Header .Background * {
  visibility: hidden; // hide the faded text
}
#Header .Foreground {
  position: absolute; // position on top of the background div
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Header">
  <div class="Background">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="Foreground">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

The important thing that every padding/margin and content must be the same in both the .Background as .Foreground.

Answer (score 13):

Relaxing your requirement to work on IE6 and legacy browsers you can use ::before and display: inline-block

```
div
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;    
}
div::before
{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:red;
  opacity: .2;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/KVyFH/172/
​

It will work on any modern browser

Comment: won't work with overflow. http://jsfiddle.net/KVyFH/256/

Comment: I suggest to also add to the "before" elemnt "top: 0; right:0" or it wouldn't work with padding

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @davy-landmann for https://stackoverflow.com/a/638064/417153.
That's what I was looking for! Same effect with LESS code:

```
  @searchResultMinHeight = 200px;
  .searchResult {
    min-height: @searchResultMinHeight;

    position: relative;
    .innerTrans {
      background: white;
      .opacity(0.5);
      min-height: @searchResultMinHeight;
    }
    .innerBody {
      padding: 0.5em;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
  }
```