# semi transparent background color but not the Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to show the div content with semi background color but not the text value

Example:

```
<div style="height:25px; background-color: red;">
 Content 
</div>
```

I want to display the div background as semi transparent and text as normally while the onmouseover event.

How can I do that.

Comment: You can give a div an .png transperent background.

Comment: This is basically the same question but has some better answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="transparentBG" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">Text</div>
    <div class="overlay" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">Text</div>
</div>
```

You can set how the styles change by having ":hover" versions of each class.

You'll have fun with multi browser support though.

Alternatively you can use two images:

```
<style>
.transparentBGOnHover { background-image: url(../images/red.png); }
.transparentBGOnHover:hover { background-image: url(../images/transparentRed.png); }
</style>

<div class="transparentBGOnHover">
    Text
</div>
```

IE6 can't handle the transparent PNG correctly without a DX filter.

You may also need to handle the hover via javascript for IE6 and IE7 as they don't support :hover correctly (despite the fact that IE5.5 invented it)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work just fine:

```
<div style="height:25px; background-color: #99FF0000;">
 Content 
</div>
```

Bobby

Comment: or background-color:rgba(255,0,0, 0.5);
more: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: @pawel: Nice, I always forget that CSS also has such functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have non-transparent content in a semi-transparent container. The content inherits the transparency from the parent. 
Here's a solution which separates the content layer and the transparent layer. All is wrapped in a div which i target with the :hover rules.

This solution is only tested in FF3.5.4, note that IE 6 has problems with :hover on any other element then `<A>`.

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper { position: relative; }
.background { background-color: red; width: 100px; height:25px; position: absolute; }
.content { width: 100px; height: 25px; position: absolute; z-index: 2; color: #fff; }
.wrapper:hover .background { opacity: 0.25; }
.wrapper:hover .content { color: #000; }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Text</div>
    <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```