# How to make a transparent background without background image?

Tags: html, css, transparent, background-color

I would like a `div` to have a transparent background.
I tried to do this using `background-color` and `opacity`, but the problem is that the border and the text inside become also transparent. [Example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/eU7By/)

Is this possible to achieve this without using transparent PNG background image ?

Comment: I would answer with `background-color: transparent` but I don't think you're looking for that. What exactly do you mean by a transparent background? *Edit:* upvoted Gaby's answer in case you *were* looking for a completely transparent background.

Comment: This is not want I'm looking for. See my comment to Gaby's answer below.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/is-it-possible-to-make-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text-in-css

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/4997493/759452

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you just want the color of the background to be transparent and not the child content, use

`background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); // Sets to 50% transparent`

See this page for more details - it's a css3 spec so won't show up in every browser:

http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/

Comment: Note that rgba is not compatible with IE8 but is compatible with IE10+ (IE9 maybe too), Firefox 3+, Safari 3+, Chrome. You can use css3pie polyfill library (see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css3pie/hot) to make this feature work on IE8 & below.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

Set 
    `background-color: transparent;`

and do not use `opacity`, as that is what makes semi-transparent the whole div..

updated your example at http://jsfiddle.net/eU7By/1/

***UPDATE*** after comments

you can use rgba for the background-color as @DHuntrods mentions. IE needs some tweaking of'course.. http://leaverou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/

Comment: I meant the that background-color should be semi transparent. In my example, the black background should be semi-transparent (according to opacity).

Answer (score 1):

**The most cross-browser solution** is to use the opacity property on an additional "absolutely positioned" child element (in a relatively or absolutely positioned parent): it only there to contain the colored transparent background.

Then you can use the `opacity` property to make this element transparent. Since this element has no children, the opacity will not affect any other element.

Opacity is an IE5+ property, just use (see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/):

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";    /* IE 8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);  /* IE 5-7 */
-moz-opacity: 0.5;          /* Netscape */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;        /* Safari 1.x */
opacity: 0.5;               /* Good browsers */
```

see the jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/DUjzX/1/

#### The whole code looks like:

**The HTML:**

```
 <div class="my-cool-wrapper">
      <div class="text-and-images-on-top">
           <p>Here some content (text AND images) "on top of the transparent background"</p>
           <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LnnghmF.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="transparent-background">
      </div>
 </div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
 .my-cool-wrapper {
      position: relative;
 }
 .my-cool-wrapper .text-and-images-on-top {
      padding: 10px 15px 19px 15px;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative; /* needed to enable the z-index */
 }
 .my-cool-wrapper .transparent-background {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;    
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";       /* IE 8 */
      filter: alpha(opacity=10);  /* IE 5-7 */
      -moz-opacity: 0.1;          /* Netscape */
      -khtml-opacity: 0.1;        /* Safari 1.x */
      opacity: 0.1;               /* Good browsers */
      background-color: blue;
 }
```

read more:
[Set opacity of background image without affecting child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements?rq=1)

**Screenshots proofs**
[image: IE7]
[image: IE8]
[image: IE9]
[image: IE10]
[image: IE11]

ps: I did not add the screenshots for Chrome, Firefox & Safari since these are much "better" browsers... trust me, it works for them too.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a 30x30 transparent gif as a background.

```
background:url('absolute path here');
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple CSS method to have a clear transparent background in html is this code.

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)!important;
```