# Set background color to trasparent CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to set the background color to transparent for this [page](https://pas.theseolounge.co.uk/custom-front-page-2/):

```
.page-id-714 .container-fluid {
  background-color: transparent;

}
```

But I do not seem to be able to address the correct class or item. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184117/transparent-css-background-color

Comment: Please provide a [mre], not a link to an external site asking us to debug an existing webpage.  Please see [How to properly ask a question where the author does not know where the problem is?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295932/691711)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting it on the wrong class. You need to set it on

```
.top-stripe {
  /* Current, it's set to background-color: #fbfbfb; */
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Make sure you declare the above after the selector which I've shared below, else you need to make your selector more specific, or you need to use `!important` which I would not recommend, or better, you remove `top-stripe` from that declaration altogether.

---

Here's the declaration on your webpage..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.top-stripe {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```