# Excel Addin transparent Dialog

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am implementing a loading dialog for Excel addin to let user know its in process, need to wait.

I have tried

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://localhost:3000/#/dialog/loading",{
                width: 100,
                height: 100
            }, function (asyncResult: Office.AsyncResult<Office.Dialog>): void {
                
              })
```

But, it will total cover the excel, and I could not see any content under dialog.

While testing with Excel Online `Copy link` -> `To Sheet`, I am able to see below behavior.

[image]

How to achieve the same behavior in Excel addin?

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color of the dialog page to transparent. There's lots of good information about doing this at [Transparent CSS background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184117/transparent-css-background-color)

Comment: It did not work. css will not make browser transparent.