# How I can animate fadin and fadeout background image in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a background-image that must be animated through fadein and fadeout effect on hover event. How I can do that?

Comment: provide the code that you have tried or place the fiddle link.

Comment: @user1671639: Not "or." Code must always be in the question itself. http://jsfiddle.net links are a useful *adjunct*, not a substitute.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right.  I forget it.  Here when adding jsfiddle link without code, SO gives an error message.  Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Also you can try using [css3 transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: but transition not supported by ie8 (

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890218/css-background-opacity
Second answer has what you need.

Answer (score 7):

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('div').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut("1000", function () {
        $(this).css("background", "url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/ff0000')").fadeIn(1000);
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut("1000", function () {
        $(this).css("background", "url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff')").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Check this [**fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/tv5JL/185/).

Incase if you wish to it using **CSS3 transition** then,

change the `CSS` like this

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    color: black;
    background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff);
    transition: background-image 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-image 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-image 1s linear;
}
div:hover {
    background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/ff0000);
}
```

[**Fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/axabX/126/)