# How to overlay black text and image on white css background?

Tags: css, image

The issue i have sounds like this: i have a background css image with an overlay white background-color and opacity 0.8 so the image behind the white bg could be a little visible. I want to add some text and another image over both backgrounds but the opacity is also active on my text & image and because of that both are hard to see.
Here is also a screenshot of what i have in this moment.
http://prnt.sc/c8uf8q

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background-image-opacity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890218/css-background-image-opacity)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

How do you set background color and opacity to overlay?
if you define properties like this:

```
.overlay{
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

then replace it with:

```
.overlay{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

Text will be visible

Comment: Here is the code i'm using to get the image from the above screenshot http://prnt.sc/c9p9ss

Comment: Remove opacity:0.8;  from  #uniquedesign::before{}
because you already set opacity value in background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); . Here last argument (0.8) represent opacity.