# change body background image property using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

i want to change my background image with **fadeIn** and **fadeOut** effect. i can change it using this code but i can't use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effect. how can i use this effects? i mean last background should have `fadeOut` effect and next background should have `fadeIn` effect. 
**note**: background property is part of body and i don't want my elements in body take `fadeIn` OR `fadeOut` effect.
jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        $("body").css("background", "url(../img/2.jpg) center center no-repeat");
        $("body").css("background-size", "cover");
    }, 3000);
});
```

css:

```
body{
    background: url(../img/1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You can't fade background images, you can only fade the div

Comment: @Eric there is no way that i can do that? any suggestions?

Comment: If you can change the DOM structure, please consider @mccambrige answer, as there is no way to do that.
If you can not change the DOM structure AND if you only have 2 or 3 background images to play with, you could also use `:before` and `:after` selector of the body (knowing these selector can not be directly accessed through Jquery) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502157/transparent-background-image/6502295#6502295

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div class="background">
         <!-- the rest of your existing body contents -->
    </div>
</body>
```

This is more of a conceptual answer. But if you tuck a `div` between your `body` tag and the rest of your current website, attach the background to that div and manipulate it that way, you'll have better results. You'll just have to figure out how to position your content over top of that `div.background`. Just make sure the background `div` is full width, height, etc. Hack on that for a while. I bet you'll figure out the rest.