# CSS transparency issues in nested elements

Tags: html, css, nested, opacity

hey there i wonder if any of you have come across a similar issue? i am working on an ad section of the webpage and its got a really cool background that i would like to carry on into sections of the elements so i have a box that hold a box for a rss feed into updates made on the website and then i have a box for adverts. here is my html:

```
<div class="side">
  <div id="ad">
    bla
  </div>
  <div id="rss_news">
    double bla
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.side {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 710px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  opacity: 0.3;

 }

 #ad {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   height: 320px;
   max-height: 350px;
   margin: 15px;
   opacity: 1;

 }

 #rss_news {
   border: 1px solid yellow;
   height: 320px;
   max-height: 350px;
   margin: 15px; 
   opacity: 1;

 }
```

as you can see and as i was anticipating the side class immits his attributes on the ones nested within him. is there a way that i could somehow tell the other id tags to ignore that opacity?

thanks in advance :D

Comment: This was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements

Comment: thanks for that link.. man i am quite bummed that there is no definitive ignore method or something. ill have to try something else.. thanks a lot for those resources

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent background, but not the content (text & images) inside it, in CSS only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css3 `rgba` property for this & for IE you can use `IE filter`.Write like this:

```
    .side{
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
      background: transparent;
      filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F000000,endColorstr=#7F000000);   /* IE*/      
      zoom: 1;
    }
```

Comment: will that work with ie. 8 browsers though. our clients are huge so we dont know what type of browsers to expect

Comment: it's work in all browsers accept IE BUT for this you can use IE filter for this. you can generate you filter from here http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to make descendants ignore the parent's `opacity`.

You can use `rgba`/`hsla` colors to get a partially transparent background, without affecting the children's visibility. Example:

```
.side {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ywQy5/

See also:

- MDN: [`hsla` colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value#HSLa_%28hue-saturation-lightness-alpha%29_hsla%28H.2CS.2CL.2Ca%29)
- MDN: [`rgba` colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value#RGBa_%28red-green-blue-alpha%29_rgba%28R.2CG.2CB.2Ca%29)