# CSS3 Transition on Hyperlink Hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have the following **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/EHrk4/2/

**Is it possible that *#main* remains opacity 1 *until* I hover over the hyperlink, then it goes to 0.3?**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">    
    <a href="#">hover me to fade out main</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background:red
}

#main:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it via jquery personally.

http://jsfiddle.net/EHrk4/5/

JQ

```
$('#link').hover(function(){
    $('#main').addClass('hover');
}, function(){
   $('#main').removeClass('hover');
})
```

CSS

```
#main {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background:red
}

.hover {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

EDIT:

From our comments, here is how to do it while still preserving the child elements opacity of 1.

http://jsfiddle.net/EHrk4/11/

Comment: Many thanks, Dylan!! This is aaaaalmost perfect. Just wondering, is it possible to keep the actual hyperlink unaffected by the opacity change? Thank you :)

Comment: Yes instead of using opacity which effects all child elements, use rgba() on the background-color property. backround-color: rgba(255,0,0,.3) for your case.

Comment: let me verify that quick i may have spoken too soon.

Comment: I figured it out, its kind of hacky tho... make sure you provide color fallbacks for older browswers that dont support rgba. http://jsfiddle.net/EHrk4/9/

Comment: scratch that, this includes your transition, and cleans up a couple lines i had hanging around that were from when i was testing things.

http://jsfiddle.net/EHrk4/11/

Comment: Many thanks, Dylan! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to want to play ball with my local version :'( I'll look into it.

Comment: Using `#link` caused some issues for me. Works great now - cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

No - your link is inside the element you want to affect, and currently there is no parent selector in CSS2 or in CSS3.

If your anchor was a sibling element of the div, you could affect the div's opacity as you wish - like in this quick **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHrk4/4/)** example.

Example of affecting sibling in pure CSS:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">hover me to fade out main</a>
<div id="main">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a:hover + #main {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

---

If it has to be inside, I'd recomend using a Javascript library such as [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) to achieve it.

---

Or, take a look at the [**the following answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997602/1586880), which explains a workaround for opacity affecting child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is posible for example:

```
#main,a{
   display:block;
   height:100px;
   width:100px;
}
```

Make the `height,width` of the anchor tag same as `#main`. So when you hover the link it will give you the affect all over the `#main`. Other wise you can use `jquery` for this.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. jQuery could be an option. Have you seen this done before using jQuery? It would be great to see an example :) Thanks

Comment: I tried your solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/EHrk4/3/ but alas, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes i done it my self as well that's why i am asking him to use jquery as a 2nd option.