# how can I partially fade out an image out with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a background image. I want to fade it out part-way when the page loads, meaning I want the effect of the [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) -- but instead of making the image invisible I want it to stop part-way so that it is semi-visible.

Is there a way of doing this with fadeout? Is there another method I could use?

Comment: `element.animate({ 'opacity': '.5'});`

Comment: take a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements

Comment: [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) as well. Oh, and looky here--a whole section on [fading](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/).

Comment: Do you want only part of the image to fade, or the entire image to be somewhere between opaque and transparent?

Comment: @j08691 the entire image to be somewhere between opaque and transparent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you tried **[.animate(properties, duration)](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** function?

```
$("#image").animate({ opacity: 0.5}, 200);
```

or you could also use **[.fadeTo(duration, opacity)](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)** function:

```
$("#image").fadeTo(2000, 0.5);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Awytu/)**