# Apply opacity without effecting the child elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `div` that has a background image, and when It got hovered, the div will be given opacity 0.7

```
<div>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Secondly I've a span that when I got hovered, I use `show()` to overwrite its default css `display:none`.

The problem is the opacity applies to the `span` as well, so the text doesn't stand out as I expect. I tried to set `span` to opacity 1 on the hover event, no luck with that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set opacity of background image without affecting child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opacity will affect all children of an element. You can achieve what you want by using two parallel divs, one for the background image with opacity and the other with the span and the rest of the `content`. The `absolute` positioning of `bg-img` will not affect the position of `content` and will appear behind this. You also want to adjust the positioning and size of `bg-img` using `top`, `bottom`, `right`, `left`, `width` or `height`

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    <div class="bg-img"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <span>text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.bg-img {
    position: absolute;
}
.bg-img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the background color behind the image is known, you can apply an opaque background color to the `<span>` to make the background image look faded.

http://jsfiddle.net/TxQny/

HTML:

```
<div class="bg">
    <span class="overlay">text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    background-color: #e0e0e0; /* You can use an image instead */
}
.overlay {
    display: block;
}
.overlay:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

Of course, this assumes that all the browsers you care about supporting support RGBA.