# Background image opacity without affecting text

Tags: html, css, background-image, opacity

I have a problem with my background image and text. I only want to apply the opacity to background image but mine, the text was affected.

HTML

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content{
    background: url(../img/103_n.jpg) left top no-repeat, url(../img/103_n.jpg) right bottom no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.content .box p{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the content a z-index of -1 and then the text a z-index of 1

Comment: Make your text position relative.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani the link you attach is using `background-color` and i need not to make my background edit the opacity

Comment: @Ven 2. Use positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link [How can i change background image opacity without changing on div content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254346/how-can-i-change-background-image-opacity-without-changing-on-div-content)

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}

.content::after {
  content: "";
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg') left top no-repeat, url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg') right bottom no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class="box">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should vote to close as duplicate

Comment: @Hien Nguyen Thanks it's working well.

Answer (score 3):

There is no background opacity property but you can fake it with pseudo element:

```
.content {
  position: relative;
}

.content::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(../img/103_n.jpg) left top no-repeat, url(../img/103_n.jpg) right bottom no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

Comment: `z-index: -1` actually just hid the image from me - maybe it was because the <body> had a bg-color and the image was just hiding behind the body. Regardless, I had to throw `z-index: 1;` on the non-pseudo background element and keep `z-index: -1;` on the pseudo element. Side not: using just `:` as opposed to `::` is supposed to support at least IE 8, but maybe even further back.

Answer (score 0):

You can using before (or) after and set opacity

```
    .content {
      position: relative;
    }

    .content ::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background:#000 \also give any color for background;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to separate the parent opacity from its children, you need to use a pseudo selector for the parent:

```
.content:after {
    content: '';    
    background: url(../img/103_n.jpg) no-repeat, url(../img/103_n.jpg) right bottom no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```