# Style the Opacity of an Element Without Styling Child Element

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` tag that I have styled to have `opacity: 0.5;`. Within that `<div>` tag I have an `<iframe>` that I don't want to have 50% opacity. I'm wondering if there's any way to style the `<div>` element and exclude the `<iframe>` element that is inside the `<div>` element.

Comment: Why you want `opacity` to be `0.5`? background? The solution is set the opacity to the child elements, except for the `iframe`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set opacity of background image without affecting child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opacity is **not inherited**, but because the parent has opacity that applies to everything within it. **You cannot make a child element less transparent than the parent**. So:

- Set the `opacity` to the child elements, except for `iframe`.
- If you have some transparent background in your parent, use `rgba` or transparent `png`.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating the rgba mentioned above. http://jsfiddle.net/z85fgupu/ Notice the black background is 0.5 opacity due to the a or alpha setting of rgba()

Comment: So then how do I add the same background color(with 50% opacity) as the other elements to the iframe(it has a border)?
EDIT: Didn't realize, if I use rgba it doesn't effect the iframe does it?

Answer (score 1):

As @ROX stated you can't. In my opinion setting opacity to other child elements can be good choice. Try this:

```
.your_div *:not(iframe) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Another option would be using a wrapper with `relative` position and all other elements with `absolute` position inside that wrapper. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9b2uxpzh/1/)

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, I tried it earlier, but thanks!

Comment: @SethTaddiken I've added another option, please see it

Comment: Thanks, that would work but personally I would rather use an rgba value as a background color.