# How can I make no-repeat for background?

Tags: javascript

I want to make no-repeat picture (background) for javascript.

```
e.target.style.backgroundImage = "url(sozai/a.jpg)";
```

In this case a.jpg will be shown as a background repeatedly but I want to have no-repeat.

Also I want to make change of transparency of the picture.

Comment: e.target.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";

Answer (score 5):

You can set background-repeat property like

```
e.target.style.backgroundImage = "url(sozai/a.jpg)";
e.target.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
```

or simplified

```
e.target.style.background = "url(sozai/a.jpg) no-repeat";
```

- [CSS Properties Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference)

Answer (score 1):

for no-repeat

```
e.target.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
```

for transparency

```
e.target.style.opacity = "0.7";
```

Comment: Changing the opacity will also affect everything inside the element, not just the background. But you can use pseudo elements to target exclusively the opacity of the background image. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements) on how to achieve this.