# Background opacity div inside div

Tags: html, css

[image]

Lets use this for example.
So you can see here red div inside of green div.
How can I make **background** of green div to have opacity, but at the same time red divs content/background keeps full visibility.

Comment: Please supply code instead of an image. Makes it easier to copy and paste an answer :)

Comment: I am sorry,il keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking for correctly, you can use an `rgba()` value as the green div's background color:

```css
.green {
  height: 400px;
  background: rgba(83,210,103,0.5);
  }
.red {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="green">
  GREEN
  <div class="red">
    RED
  </div>
</div>
```

`rgba()` takes the three normal values of red, green, blue (rgb) as well as an **alpha** value with `1` being default opaque, 0.5 half-opaque, etc.

Comment: I used green only as example,What if i want to make patternt transparent ?

Comment: @Aco Ah, after re-looking at your above comment, you'll want to check the following out: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements)