# how I add a transparent background in html

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background around a part of my text to make it easy to read as my background image makes it hard and change the colour of my text is not highly desirable

Comment: can you post your code or else the screenshot of your work. I very difficult to understand your problem without clear explanation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements

Comment: I would add image but this site won't allow me

Comment: And it allow me to add code either something about ctrl k but I doing everything from an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following lines in your CSS:

```
background-image: url(img_flwr.gif);
opacity: 0.6;
```