# How to make background image opacity change without the entire body div changing?

Tags: html, css

I have created an ID for my HTML body called #indexbody. I put a background image with CSS using `background-image:url("hs2.webp");`. Because I Have done it this way, is there a way to change the background opacity of my image without dimming the entire body?

CSS:

```
#indexbody{
  background-image:url("hs2.webp");
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: Look at using a pseudo element.

Comment: @AHaworth What would it look like, im rusty on those. I tried "#indexbody::background-image{
  opacity: 0.5;
}" which doesnt work.

Comment: Try using a ::before pseudo element. MDN is a good source of info on CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set opacity of background image without affecting child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements)

Comment: @AHaworth still confused. Is it #indexbody::before{

Answer (score 1):

If you put the background-image on the before pseudo image rather than the actual body element you can set its opacity down without that affecting the whole body element.

Here's a simple snippet:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this. One of the most common is using a pseudo-element. In this case, I used `:after` to create the background color overtop of the picture then used `z-index` to make sure my absolutely positioned text elements are layered ahead of the pseudo-element.

```css
#indexbody {
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff");
  /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); --> solution without using psuedo-element */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#indexbody:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: .5;
  inset: 0;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="indexbody">
  <p>absolutely positioned element overtop, unaffected by opacity</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the :before or :after CSS pseudo-elements, you apply the div with a background image and set an opacity on it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).