# How can I cancel the opacity of a child div?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a div here with a button:

[image: Menu with semi-opaque button]

I want the contents of the div to be opaque while still keeping the semi-opaque background color.

The box will contain a menu.

```
#calculationMenu {
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px solid #1F5899 ;
height: 200px;
width: 400px; 
padding: 20px;
opacity:0.4;
background-color: #6AA6D9;

}
div.calcMenuContents {
opacity: 1;
}
```

The Run button is contained within the calcMenuContents div:

```
<div id="calculationMenu">
<div id="calcMenuContents">

    <button onclick="runCalculations(2)" class="insideMenu">Run</button> 

</div>
</div>
```

How may I make it so that the calcMenuContents are not semi-transparent?

Update: Thank you, BoltClock for the alternate solution (to set specific attributes of a div, instead of for the entire div).
My only issue is that the parent

[image: Fixed menu]

Comment: Use a `rgba()` colour: http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/

Comment: See my answer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807286/how-to-make-div-background-color-transparent-in-css

Comment: I think you submitted your edit a little too early...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really cancel out a parent element's opacity, but if the only parts of the parent element that will be semi-transparent are its background and its border, you can replace their hex colors with `rgba()` values based on the opacity you had given it, and remove the `opacity` declarations altogether:

```
#calculationMenu {
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px solid rgba(31, 88, 153, 0.4);
height: 200px;
width: 400px; 
padding: 20px;
background-color: rgba(106, 166, 217, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! My menu is beautiful now.

 I see how that works now.

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution! Use rgba background values and you can have transparency wherever you want :

```
#calculationMenu
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    /*opacity: 0.4;*/
    padding: 20px;
}

div.calcMenuContents
{
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
    /*opacity: 1;*/
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/TK8Lq/1/

---

For text, you can just use the same rgba code, but set to the color property of CSS:

```
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

But you must use rgba on everything for this to work, you have to remove the opacity for all parent elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/TK8Lq/2/

use [rgba()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color)

Answer (score 2):

you can change the background-color into an RGBA, so you would get:

```
background-color: rgba(106, 166, 217, 0.4);
```

If I'm right

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the opacity of child elements. Try to use semi-transparent .png image as background of "calculationMenu" div instead of solid color background and opacity.