# Transparent sidebars on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, background, transparent

My current website is wordpress and I have added two sidebars on my homepage which is a one page parallax. I am confused as to how to add transparent background both of them.

I've tried to add this:

```
#main .sidebar {background-color: transparent;padding: 0px;}
```

But nothing changes. This is my [demo](http://new.vintageathens.gr/)

Any kind of help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: By `main .sidebar` do you mean `#main .sidebar`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make div background color transparent in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807286/how-to-make-div-background-color-transparent-in-css)

Comment: Mtinsley thank you for your comment,yes i mean #main .sidebar

Comment: Jezrael thank you for your advice, i am very new in css etc but i ;ll study the instructions in the link..