# Click event on whole page when iframe exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have several iframes in my page and then this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
                if (x) {
                    action();
                }
                else if(y) {
                    anotherAction();    
                };
```

So when I click anywhere in the page, I would like my page to perform a specific action. But since the iframe is there, I am actually clicking on the iframe and nothing happens. How can I get around this? Maybe setting the iframe as a background image or something along those lines?

Comment: Is the iframe serving content from the same origin as the page you're working on?

Comment: it is not, unfortunately

Comment: Then I don't think there would be a good workaround for this. If you don't care about a user being able to interact with the iframe you can use another element to overlay it.

Comment: user interaction with the iframe is not entirely necessary in my case but it would be nice to have. How would you overlay it with an element?

Answer (score 1):

The iframe is technically displaying a different document and what you do in yours doesn't affect what goes inside of the iframe.

Quickest way around it I can think of is placing a transparent div of your own over the iframe, making it so content from your page is covering the iframe content, but that might not be a proper solution depending on what the iframe is supposed to display.

Comment: how would you make a transparent div? I did `<div class="invisibleOverlay" style="background-color:transparent;"></div>` but it is still covering the iframes

Comment: interesting - I tried everything here but nothing worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807286/how-to-make-div-background-color-transparent-in-css

Comment: @jgozal It should be transparent by default. Possibly some other CSS messing with it? Try `visibility: hidden`

Comment: I had my scroll bar hidden so I didn't realize the div actually moved the iframes down (because the iframes are in divs as well). must be something with the position property, need to refresh my memory on it

Comment: nothing. I think it is because I am running a setInterval with the iframes which makes them overlay the div every interval

Comment: @jgozal In that case you could try setting the `z-index` on the overlay (making sure to set the `position` to either `relative` or `absolute`).

Comment: Try to add a z-index to the div perhaps?