# how to cancel opacity for a child element?

Tags: css, opacity

I want apply opacity for parent but I do not want the child element to inherit this opacity.

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Is there a way to "cancel" the inherited opacity? maybe force it to `opacity=1`for the child element?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The opacity of the child will always be the opacity of the parent if the opacity of the child is 1.

This is not a problem with inheritance, but rather with the way opacity is calculated.

For instance,

```
<div id="parent">
    <div></div>
</div>

<div id="original">
</div>

<div id="quarter">
</div>

#parent div, #quarter {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
}

#parent div {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#parent {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#quarter {
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```

`#quarter`'s opacity, from your perspective, is the same as that of `#parent div`, but in actual fact, `#parent div` has twice the opacity of `#quarter`. See this jsfiddle for more detail: http://jsfiddle.net/HUaNm/

---

The only way to avoid this is to move the child out of the parent. Alternatively, depending on what you want here, you can also use `rgba` colors for the background/border/font color of the parent instead of opacity, but the effect is not the same as applying opacity.

Comment: This was driving me nuts. If only the browsers would support opacity:1.5 or some other way to over reference this would be a non issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you have parent background color - use RGBA,
if you have parent image - use additional RGBA layer between parent and child divs playing with css position.