# CSS opacity - do not affect child elements

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to not apply opacity for child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182304/how-to-not-apply-opacity-for-child-element)

Is it possible with css or jquery to apply transparency/opacity to an element and not have that affect child elements?

Comment: No it's not! You could use RGBA background colors to get a somewhat similar result.

Comment: I believe it is not possible. Opacity includes all children of the element. What effect would you like to achieve? Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: You would need to specifically set the CSS of the child elements as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you will want to set the background opacity

```
/* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
/* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
```

Check out [this blog](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/) for further support

Answer (score 1):

No, transparency is inherited, but you can use RGBA (alpha channel) instead.

A good example & tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/