# how to make a div transparent without affecting the child in CSS 3?

Tags: html, css

how to make a div transparent without affecting the child in CSS 3

here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="icon">
   <ul>
      <li><a href=""><img src="Iconpaper.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="Movies.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="Phone.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="Stocks.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="Love.png"></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="search">
    SEARCH
</div>

</div>
```

and here's the CSS:-

```
#header{
   background-color:#000;
   width:1349px;
   height:60px;
   position:fixed;
   z-index:2;
   opacity:0.7;
   }
#icon{
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
   }
li{
   display:inline;
  }
#header img{
   width:35px;
   height:35px;
  }
#search{
   float:right;
   color:#e5e5e5;
   padding:20px;
   font-size:20px;
  }
```

so, I want to make the #header div tranparent and fixed without affecting the #icon and #search div.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of [how to not apply opacity for child element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182304/how-to-not-apply-opacity-for-child-element) ([and many, many others](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=opacity+children+stack+overflow)).

Comment: If you just want to make the background color transparent, then you could use `rgba` and remove the `opacity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `opacity`, use `rgba()` like `background: rgba(0,0,0,.7)` where `a` stands for alpha/opacity. So change the below block of code like

```
#header{
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7); /* 0.7 Opacity for black */
   width:1349px;
   height:60px;
   position:fixed;
   z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the exact thing i needed.

Comment: @RahulKhatri consider marking the answer as correct by clicking on the tick besides my answer, this way it will help fuure visitors to refer

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, a child's opacity is always calculated based on its parent. So to answer your question, you cannot set a parent's opacity to 0.5 and still have the child display with an opacity of 1.0.

Example:

- Parent element: `opacity: 0.5;` (actual opacity = `0.5`)
- Child element: `opacity: 1.0;` (actual opacity is `0.5 * 1.0 = 0.5`)

Answer (score 0):

Use a repeating semi-transparent png for the background or use rgba color value.