# Why opacity property which is applied to parent element affecting its child element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have applied background-image to div with class="hero-contact-us" and opacity=0.3. I am not able to figure out why opacity property is applied to the child element with class="hero-contact-us-text". I will really appreciate your help.

```
<div class="hero-contact-us">
    <div class="hero-contact-us-text">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.hero-contact-us
{
    background-image: url('media/pexels-ruslan-burlaka-140945.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: relative;
}

.hero-contact-us-text
{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    color:#173348;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Because `hero-contact-us` is a parent.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `.hero-contact-u-text` is inside the `.hero-contact-us`. whatever your css styles of the parent, it will affect its children elements. What you can do is to remove the background styles in your parent and create another `div` inside `.hero-contact-us` solely for the purpose of the background image. You can set the background-image and opacity of that `div` and you can stretch it out using `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

All CSS defined in the parent element will apply to everything within it. It means that you cannot make a child element less transparent than the parent, without some trickery.
How to make some trickery?
Please have a look at this link.

[how to cancel opacity for a child element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182304/how-to-cancel-opacity-for-a-child-element)