# How do I make a semi transparent background?

Tags: css

I need to make a white background 50% transparent without affecting anything else. How do I do it?

Comment: here is a link to an article that describes the method for implementing transparency using CSS. http://www.domedia.org/oveklykken/css-transparency.php
Beware though it seems that cross browser support can be an issue which may cause you to change your implementation.

Comment: Do you mean how to set an opacity to a div background without affecting the nested elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Use `rgba()`:

```
.transparent {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

This will give you 50% opacity while the content of the box will continue to have 100% opacity.

If you use `opacity:0.5`, the content will be faded as well as the background. Hence do not use it.

Comment: yes, IE supports rgba, its syntax is #ARGB and is written as filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#AARRGGBBAA,endColorstr=#AARRGGBBAA);

its basically a gradient of a static color but with transparency.

Comment: Change `background:` with `background-color:`

Comment: `background-color` is not more correct than `background`.

Comment: @Sean Is it more specific and intention-revealing, then? Personally I prefer to use it in this case, but is there a reason that's not a good preference?

Comment: @DaveSlutzkin It's a fine preference to have and there's nothing wrong with it, but edits should not be made based on personal preference. Otherwise, questions will keep oscillating between different versions as people with opposing preferences encounter them.

Answer (score 16):

This works, but all the children of the element with this class will also become transparent, without any way of preventing that.

```
.css-class-name {
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to make transparent background is gray, pls try:

```
   .transparent{
       background:rgba(1,1,1,0.5);
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Good to know**

Some web browsers have difficulty to render text with shadows on top of transparent background. Then you can use a semi transparent 1x1 PNG image as a background.

**Note**

Remember that IE6 don’t support PNG files.

Comment: IE6 does support PNGs, even transparent ones: filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod=scale, src='/filename.png');

Comment: @manmal but where do you put your IE fix? Directly in the site .css file?

Comment: @Thalatta yes, just try it.

Answer (score 3):

DO NOT use a 1x1 semi transparent PNG. Size the PNG up to 10x10, 100x100, etc. Whatever makes sense on your page. (I used a 200x200 PNG and it was only 0.25 kb, so there's no real concern over file size here.)

After visiting this post, I created my web page with 3, 1x1 PNGs with varying transparency.

Dreamweaver CS5 was tanking. I was having flash backs to DOS!!! Apparently any time I tried to scroll, insert text, basically do anything, DW was trying to reload the semi transparent areas 1x1 pixel at a time ... YIKES!

Adobe tech support didn't even know what the problem was, but told me to rebuild the file (it worked on their systems, incidentally). It was only when I loaded the first transparent PNG into the css file that the doc dove deep again.

Then I found a post on another help site about PNGs crashing Dreamweaver. Size your PNG up; there's no downside to doing so.

Comment: Sizing up a PNG just because your tool is so crappy that it doesn't support it? Really...

Answer (score 0):

Although dated, not one answer on this thread can be used universally. Using rgba to create transparent color masks - that doesn't exactly explain how to do so with background images.

My solution works for background images or color backgrounds.

```css
#parent {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #476172;
    background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random');
    line-height: 29px;
    text-align:center;
}

#content {
    color: white;
    height: 125px !important;
    width: 125px !important;
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="parent"><a href="" id="content" title="content" rel="home">Example</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.main{
     width:100%;
     height:550px;
     background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503135935062-
     b7d1f5a0690f?ixlib=rb-enter code here0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=cf4d0c234ecaecd14f51a2343cc89b6c&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=376&h=564&q=60&cs=tinysrgb') no-repeat;
     background-position:center;
     background-size:cover 
}
 div.main>div{
     width:100px;
     height:320px;
     background:transparent;
     background-attachment:fixed;
     border-top:25px solid orange;
     border-left:120px solid orange;
     border-bottom:25px solid orange;
     border-right:10px solid orange;
     margin-left:150px 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and sort. Use hsla css function like below

```
.transparent {
   background-color: hsla(0,0%,4%,.4);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
.transparent
{ 
  opacity:.50;
  -moz-opacity:.50; 
  filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
}
```

Comment: this will make content have 50% opacity as well.

Comment: This can easily be fixed by the css: `.transparent * { opacity:1; }`, unless, for example, an element with the `transparent` class has inner html