# CSS opacity only to background color, not the text on it?

Tags: css, opacity

Can I assign the `opacity` property to the `background` property of a `div` only and not to the text on it?

I've tried:

```
background: #CCC;
opacity: 0.6;
```

but this doesn't change the opacity.

Comment: For a cross browser method, see an earlier answer I gave: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792090/cross-browser-rgba-background/4792173#4792173 It's basically `rgba`, but it works everywhere.

Comment: This question was asked in January -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637921/opacity-of-background-not-text

Comment: A second same January asked question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790563/how-do-i-make-a-semi-transparent-background

Comment: Custom properties enables you to do this in a similar way to SCSS and LESS

```background: rgba(var(--customColour), 60%)```

Answer (score 1610, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a transparent background, in which case you could try using the [`rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb()_and_rgba()) function:

> #### `rgba(R, G, B, A)`
>
> R (red), G (green), and B (blue) can be either `<integer>`s or `<percentage>`s, where the number 255 corresponds to 100%. A (alpha) can be a `<number>` between 0 and 1, or a `<percentage>`, where the number 1 corresponds to 100% (full opacity).
>
> #### RGBa example
>
> ```
> background: rgba(51, 170, 51, .1)    /*  10% opaque green */ 
> background: rgba(51, 170, 51, .4)    /*  40% opaque green */ 
> background: rgba(51, 170, 51, .7)    /*  70% opaque green */ 
> background: rgba(51, 170, 51,  1)    /* full opaque green */
> ```

A small [example](http://jsfiddle.net/swQx2/) showing how `rgba` can be used.

As of 2018, practically [**every browser supports the `rgba` syntax**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors).

Comment: @adam Just so you know, this will not work in IE.

Comment: Dang..why is it always the IE that spoils the fun?!

Comment: It works fine in IE9+ ;o)

Comment: its not woks in mozilla firefox

Comment: background-color: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5); works Chrome,Mozilla,IE 10 as well

Comment: css3pie implements this css3 feature for older browsers such as IE8 & IE9 (as well as many others, ie. rounded corners & gradients), see http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1133

Comment: What if the background is an image and you want to adjust its opacity without affecting all of its children?

Comment: Yes, using rgba() works in most cases, but it would be nice if there was a "background-opacity:" property in css, because when the "background-color:" is set dynamically (on the fly) as an input to a settings function in an admin appearance panel, which has been coded to use only rgb(), and you don't want to override that in your css, because then the dynamic input in your function would not work. In that case, the only way to add opacity is to modify html.  If there was a "background-opacity" property, then no html code modifications would be necessary...

Comment: any other way to use this with hex codes?

Comment: If you use SASS, `transparentize ` allows you to reuse your RGB color variables and still apply an opacity: https://codepen.io/timharbour/pen/cBLqi

Comment: Is there any way to use hex codes in the `rgba` function (e.g. `rgba(0xff, 0xc4, 0x27, .5)` ?

Answer (score 87):

The easiest way to do this is with 2 divs, 1 with the background and 1 with the text:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
#block {
  background: #CCC;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  /* IE */
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  /* Mozilla */
  opacity: 0.6;
  /* CSS3 */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="block"></div>
  <div id="text">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: following property - "position: absolute;" is must in #text class for the effect to work.

Comment: But this will not be a good idea, in case we have another absolute positioned div who's position depends on parent relative element of #container

Comment: And what happens when you need your #block opac background placement to be determined by your text? For instance: hovering over a promo block brings up text half the size of the promo block. The #block layer won't respond to the text height.

Comment: I like this answer than fiddling with rgba since it's better supported.  But why does #text have to be position absolute?  With the #block in position absolute, it's out of the flow and won't affect the other elements in the page.

Answer (score 50):

**For [Less](http://lesscss.org) users only:**

If you don't like to set your colors using RGBA, but rather using HEX, there are solutions.

You could use a mixin like:

```
.transparentBackgroundColorMixin(@alpha,@color) {
  background-color: rgba(red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @alpha);
}
```

And use it like:

```
.myClass {
    .transparentBackgroundColorMixin(0.6,#FFFFFF);
}
```

Actually this is what a [built-in Less function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade) also provide:

```
.myClass {
    background-color: fade(#FFFFFF, 50%);
}
```

See *[How do I convert a hexadecimal color to rgba with the Less compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860874/how-do-i-convert-a-hexadecimal-color-to-rgba-with-the-less-compiler)*

Comment: You could also achieve this without Less or mixins by modifying the end of the string of the hex value with inline style https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

Comment: Thanks! I am using SCSS and did something like this: `background-color: rgba(red($primary), green($primary), blue($primary), 0.25);`

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. I want a 100% transparent background color. Just use this code; it's worked great for me:

```
rgba(54, 25, 25, .00004);
```

You can see examples on the [left side on this web page](http://www.chi-renovation.com) (the contact form area).

Comment: If you actually want 100% transparent, why aren't you using `rgba(54, 25, 25, 0);`? Most modern browsers won't round until the 15th decimal, but the visual difference is most likely pretty minimal between your 99.996% transparent and just using 100% transparent.

Answer (score 10):

My trick is to create a transparent .png with the color and use `background:url()`.

Comment: That's the best solution if you're dealing with legacy browsers, IMO.

Answer (score 8):

This will work with every browser

```
div {
    -khtml-opacity: .50;
    -moz-opacity: .50;
    -ms-filter: ”alpha(opacity=50)”;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
    opacity: .50;
}
```

If you don't want transparency to affect the entire container and its children, check this workaround. You must have an absolutely positioned child with a relatively positioned parent to achieve this. *[CSS Opacity That Doesn’t Affect Child Elements](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/)*

Check a working demo at *[CSS Opacity That Doesn't Affect "Children"](http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/css-opacity/css-opacity-demo.html)*

Comment: This affects the foreground.  OP asked specifically for background only.

Comment: @DSoa any solution for background only? but using rgb and alpha in different css lines

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming across this thread, here's a script called thatsNotYoChild.js that I just wrote that solves this problem automatically:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/fixing-parent-child-opacity/

Basically, it separates children from the parent element, but keeps the element in the same physical location on the page.

Answer (score 4):

A great way to do this would be to use CSS 3 indeed.

Create a div width a class - e.g. supersizer on top of your page:

Then set following CSS properties:

```css
  .supersizer {
    background: url("http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/099/d/f/stackoverflow_16x16_icon_by_muntoo_stock-d4vl2v4.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="supersizer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to create 3 `divs`. One that will contain the other 2, the one with transparent background and the one with content. Make the first div's position relative and  set the one with transparent background to negative `z-index`, then adjust the position of the content to fit over the transparent background. This way you won't have issues with absolute positioning.

Comment: Each one of 3 divs should be set to relative positioning so then they can be moved and adjusted inside the parent div, and also the parent div (if needed) moved in context of the whole page. Div with transparent background and the one with content should not contain each other. They shold be sibiling in first div.

Answer (score -12):

Use:

```
background:url("location of image"); // Use an image with opacity
```

This method will work in all browsers.

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted to use an image, though it doesn't state that. Didn't vote down for this, just trying to clarify.

Answer (score -31):

You can't. You have to have a separate div that is just that background, so that you can only apply the opacity to that.

I tried doing this recently, and since I was already using jQuery, I found the following to be the least hassle:

1. Create the two different divs. They'll be siblings, not contained in each other or anything.
2. Give the `text` div a solid background color, because that will be the JavaScript-less default.
3. Use jQuery to get the `text` div's height, and apply it to the `background` div.

I'm sure there's some kind of CSS ninja way to do all this with only floats or something, but I didn't have the patience to figure it out.

Comment: `background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);` must be the css ninja you are talking about. :)