# CSS3 Opacity issue

Tags: html, css

Here is the project site: [Site Redesign](http://projects.kcmartz.com/SiteRedesign/).

What I'm trying to do is keep the backgrounds for each section to be at the 0.5-0.7 opacity, but the text in all the content at 1.0

I've tried making a class 'text' with opacity 1.0 but that doesnt do anything, and I don't want to lose the opacity currently there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your answer is here: [CSS opacity only to background color not the text on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135019/css-opacity-only-to-background-color-not-the-text-on-it).

You want to specify the transparent background with the `background` property.