# How can I get a opacity background box without causing my other div boxes to go transparent

Tags: css

How can I get a opacity background box without causing my other div boxes to go transparent. Here is the code I am using to get my opacity box around the current boxes on the page but the code causes all div boxes to become transparent. How can I fix this issue.

```
<style>
    #background
  {
  width:400px;
  height:180px;
  margin:30px 50px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }
</style>
<div id="background">
<?php
require "../login/config.php";  
$host='';
$db = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
  mysql_select_db('');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
$name=$_POST["element_1"];
$stdatemm=$_POST["element_2_1"];
$stdatedd=$_POST["element_2_2"];
$stdateyy=$_POST["element_2_3"];
$endatemm=$_POST["element_3_1"];
$endatedd=$_POST["element_3_2"];
$endateyy=$_POST["element_3_3"];
$staddr=$_POST["element_4_1"];
$addr2=$_POST["element_4_2"];
$city=$_POST["element_4_3"];
$state=$_POST["element_4_4"];
$zip=$_POST["element_4_5"];
$desc=$_POST["element_5"];
//$file=$_FILES['element_6'];
$link=$_POST["element_7"];
$stdate=$stdatemm."/".$stdatedd."/".$stdateyy;
$endate=$endatemm."/".$endatedd."/".$endateyy;
$user=$_POST["postuser"];
if(($_FILES['element_6']['size']) > '0') {

$fileName = $_FILES['element_6']['name'];

$tmpName  = $_FILES['element_6']['tmp_name'];

$fileSize = $_FILES['element_6']['size'];

$fileType = $_FILES['element_6']['type'];

if($fileName != "")
{
if(move_uploaded_file ($tmpName, '../login/image/'.$fileName))//image is a folder in   which you will save image
{
     $query = "INSERT INTO MOdeals (fname,stdate,endate,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip,name,size,type,content,link,description,user) VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "','$stdate','$endate','" . mysql_real_escape_string($staddr) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($addr2) . "','$city','$state','$zip','" . mysql_real_escape_string($fileName) . "','$fileSize','$fileType','" . mysql_real_escape_string($content) . "','$_POST[element_7]','" . mysql_real_escape_string($desc) . "','$user')";

} } } else  
$query = "INSERT INTO MOdeals (fname,stdate,endate,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip,name,size,type,content,link,description,user) VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "','$stdate','$endate','" . mysql_real_escape_string($staddr) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($addr2) . "','$city','$state','$zip',' ','0',' ',' ','$_POST[element_7]','" . mysql_real_escape_string($desc) . "','$user')";

$q2=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'. mysql_error());
if($q2) {
echo ""; } else {
echo "error";
}        
}   

//mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MOdeals ORDER BY stdate DESC");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT stdate FROM MOdeals ORDER BY id ASC");
$y=1;
$result2 = mysql_real_escape_string($result);
echo "<div id='left' style='min-height:700px;margin-top: 2px;'><table style='-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;border-bottom:1px solid gray;background-color:white;float: left;text-align: left;margin: auto;width: 75%;'><tr style='font-weight:bold;'><td></td>  <td>Title</td><td>Start Date</td><td>City</td></tr>";
//header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
$abcd = $row['fname'];
echo "<tr><td><img src='../login/image/".$row['name']."'style='width: 145px;height: 154px;'></td>";
  echo '<td><form action="deals.php" method="get" style="margin:0px;"><input type="hidden" value="';
  echo $abcd;
  echo '" name="name"><input type="submit" style="background-color: white;border: none;color: #FF0000;text-decoration: underline;" name="submit2" value="';
  echo $abcd;
  echo '"></form><br/>';
  echo "</td><td>".$row['stdate']."</td>";
  echo "</td><td>".$row['city']."</td></tr>";
  $y++;
  }
  echo "</table></div>";
  echo "<div id='right' style='margin-top: -695px;-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;background-color:white;height:49px;'><div style = 'margin-top: -95px;margin-left: -85px;margin-right: -85px;'><p><div class='center'>
<img src='../../pictures/addeals.jpg' width='100%' height='100%'>
</div></div></div>";
  echo "<div id='right2' style='margin-top: -455px;margin-bottom: -455px;-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;background-color:white;height:49px;'><div style = 'margin- top: -95px;margin-left: -85px;margin-right: -85px;'><p><div class='center'>
<img src='../../pictures/win.jpg' width='100%' height='100%'>
</div></div></div>";


?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS opacity only to background color not the text on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135019/css-opacity-only-to-background-color-not-the-text-on-it)

Comment: This doesn't necessarily have anything to do with CSS3, as IE8 support is a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Change these:

```
background-color:#ffffff;
opacity:0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```

To this:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
```

Note that for IE8 support, the best way to achieve the above would be to use a repeated 1x1 pixel transparent PNG image as a background.

Comment: +1 But if IE8 is a requirement, then note that [`rgba()` is not supported in IE8](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors).

Comment: If you must have a transparent background on IE8 and under, I suggest using a transparent PNG for a background.

Comment: Don't suggest it to me then - add it to your answer :)

Comment: *Do not* use an image to achieve this, unless the structure of your code requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` for the background, a `div` for the content, and a wrapper for both. Set the content and background to fill the wrapper, using a `position` of `absolute`, and `width`/`height` set to `100%`. Then layer the content on top of the background using `left` of and `top` to that of the background's own value. If you do not want to absolutely position the wrapper, you can set it's `position` to `relative`.

It works by creating two separate layers, so that opacity changes to the background layer will not effect the content layer.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="content">Hello World!</div>
</div>
<style>
    body { background-color:#000 }

    .wrapper { height:200px; left:50%; margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; position:absolute; top:50%; width:200px }

    .wrapper > .background,
    .wrapper > .content { height:100%; left:0px; position:absolute; top:0px; width:100% }

    .wrapper > .background { background-color:#fff; filter:alpha(opacity=60); opacity:0.6 }
</style>
```

View the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbTWE/show/
Edit the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbTWE/