# Make background transperent and text not

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

Using 
`opacity` I made my whole `div` transparent but I want to mantain the font normal without opacity. I am unable to set a separate class or id to the content since it is dynamically created. I also cannot use the following: `background: rgba();`

```
{opacity : '0.3'}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent background, but not the content (text & images) inside it, in CSS only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on)

Comment: Any reason you cannot use `background: rgba();` ? Perhaps you can use something more specific like `background-color`.

Comment: What about creating transparent image `1px` x `1px` and setting it as a background , background-image ? Also post the relevant `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to add a background image **Transparent background.**

then on that image when you add the content it will show up with opacity of 100%.

see this [Opacity ,RGBA](http://www.css3.info/opacity_rgba_and_compromise/)

Answer (score 0):

Use rgba pattern

```
P{
   color:#fff;
    display:block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/giregaji/2/)**

Comment: If he made the `DIV` container `opacity: 0.3;` your example will be of no help as it targets `p`

Comment: You might want to add `background: rgb(0,0,0,0.60);` as a fallback for older browsers. Add it before the `rgba` rule. Otherwise they won't have a bg color at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `background: rgba()` the other work around is to use two separate containers, one for the background and the other for text. Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5135431/2965281

Comment: Sorry as I said I cannot use any selector since my page is generated.

Comment: Then, you can try using inline styles in your generator

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with both

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) /* rgb for (0,0,0) is black; opacity of 0.3 */
```

or

```
background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0.3) /* same */
```

The "a" stands for alpha channel.

There is one problem: It doesn't work with all browsers, unfortunately.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TGL45/

To learn more:

http://css-tricks.com/yay-for-hsla/

http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score -1):

Use RGBA format for background color.
You can try below code for background opacity:

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V7uc7/9/)**

```
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
```