# How to change alpha value or background color using css only; spliting color(r,g,b) and alpha(a) in different line?

Tags: css, background-color, opacity, alpha, rgba

'primary-bg' is user data whereas opacity is static. 
How can i set the opacity of background color only using css only.

```
<div class="tab-content primary-bg">
    <div class="tab-pane">XYZ</div>
</div>

.primary-bg{
   background-color: rgb(13, 148, 244);
}

.tab-content{
   //background-color opacity set to 10%
}
```

Comment: rgba = (r,g,b,alpha)  ?

Comment: @MihaiT RGB value comes from user end and i just need control over alpha value.

Comment: The height of the div changes so i cannot specify height (as suggested in that answered question)

Comment: from the duplicate; https://stackoverflow.com/a/5135431/8620333 (you need an extra layer)

Comment: I believe extra layer is not a better approach as the height of the div is not static.
Also, it seems like rgba values cannot be split.