# How to make semi-transparent background

Tags: html, css

How to make semi-transparent background using css in  element? but the content in  not transparent too? sorry for bad english. Thank you.

Comment: use `opacity` css property.

Comment: Do you want a semi transparent background color or image?

Comment: Add this to your CSS `background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5)`. Increase or decrease the `0.5` to lower or raise the opacity.

Comment: @MarsOne If he wants a semi transparent background-image it's a totally different question

Comment: @Mr_Green: `opacity` would affect all the contents of the element, not just the background.

Comment: @cHao ya thanks for pinging me to let me know :)

Comment: @itay, i want background color
to others. thank you for referrence. i am new in stack overflow, and i am beginner in programming. i need guidance from you are. one more thank you so much.

Comment: Here's a third duplicate question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790563/how-do-i-make-a-semi-transparent-background

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use rgba background.

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

values are in order red intensity, green intensity, blue intensity

the decimal value is the opacity, and it runs from 0 to 1.

if you need to customize it without too many difficulties, check out: [css3 maker](http://www.css3maker.com/css-3-rgba.html)

Comment: If the element you're talking about isn't the `body` of the document, you can also use `opacity:(decimal from 0 to 1)`

Comment: @jCuber: If it doesn't contain anything other than the image, you mean.  If you set `opacity: 50%` on a container, though, it fades out all of the element's contents as well.

Comment: @cHao Ah, good point. Anyways, the opacity attribute is also useful in cases :)

Comment: @jCuber: That it is.  Even in this case, you could probably have a `:before` pseudo-element absolutely positioned and z-indexed, and set *its* opacity rather than the container's.  But that is probably overthinking things.  :P