# Borders with opacity?

Tags: css, border, opacity

How would you do borders with opacity in CSS? `RGBA` colors aren't working for me...

[A JSFiddle is self explaining.](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/6sXcT/2/)

There are dark corners in the border, and the background of the element is visible behind it instead of the other elements behind it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a better way, but this works:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXcT/9/)

Basically, just use a wrapper `div` with the `rgba` set as a background.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="boxOuter">
    <div id="box">THANK YOU!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box{
    background-color:#ccc;font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
    height:100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:20px;
}
#boxOuter {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); width:300px; padding: 10px;
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

Read the comments to this answer to see how to make this method (`rgba`) work with older browsers.

---

A way to do it without using a wrapper:

Use [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/outline) instead of `border`, it looks acceptable:

```
outline: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXcT/14/) (it's your exact code, with the one word changed)

*(I'm not considering IE here in the slightest)*

---

Check out this article:

http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/

Comment: Now to see if there's a way to do it without a wrapper `div`.. :)

Comment: That works awesomely, thanks! I don't think there is a "no-wrapper" way, but go ahead and try!

Comment: A good point about using the wrapper `div` method is that you can make it work in older browsers. See [a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792090/cross-browser-rgba-background/4792173#4792173) of mine for cross browser rgba backgrounds.

Comment: Chris Coyer put out a great [article](http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/) on that. I recommend you check it out.

Comment: @Connor Montgomery: Thanks, that Coyier article was a good read. I was very glad to see `If you'd more complete browser compatibility, you can always go with the double-div method.` - it means that my answer thrown together in a few minutes is still applicable advice. I'm putting a link to that article in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 1st answer is the best though you can use images in borders now, try using a png image with transparency (via photoshop) use the border-image property, there's so many ways to use it you may find another style you prefer in the research.

http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/