# thickbox messege alert css change

Tags: css, thickbox

I'm trying to incorporate thickbox on my site.  Basically, it's just a fancy javascript alert with a lot more functionality.  However, when you the thickbox appears it darkens the rest of the screen.  Id rather not have this.  I have searched the CSS file extensively and cannot find how to change the opacity/background color.  Any help would be appreciated.

link to CSS file:
http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/thickbox-code/thickbox.css

Answer (score 0):

```
.TB_overlayBG {
    background-color:#000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75);
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

The "darkening of the screen" is caused by a black overlay with 75% opacity.
Change `background-color` to `transparent` if you do not want this.

Answer (score 0):

It's this:

```
.TB_overlayBG {
    background-color:#000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75);
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

You can just empty the content or remove it altogether and problem is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

@riku; you can use `rgba` for transparent color, like this

**css:**

```
.TB_overlayBG {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000,endColorstr=#4C000000); /* IE 6 & 7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000,endColorstr=#4C000000)"; /* IE8 */

}
```

Because `rgba` is not transparent it's content as `opacity` does

For more check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662178/opacity-of-divs-background-without-affecting-contained-element-in-ie-8/5662237#5662237)