# CSS3PIE - how trouble free is it for IE6 - IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, css3pie

I'm wondering if folks can tell me how trouble free CSS3PIE is for IE6 - IE8 (beyond the [known issues](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/)).  It seems like an excellent addition to allow one to use CSS3 features -- rounded corners, gradients, shadows, etc -- I just have limited time to invest into investigating stability / errors.

Thanks

P.S. Does it turn off automatically in browsers that support CSS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has worked perfectly for me and it only affects IE so you dont have to worry about the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry it's transparent.
The only "real" problem I've been having was with opacity transitions in ie8 :
In order to make a div fade out, you need to apply this css definition to every child element :

```
filter: inherit
```

Problem is it doesn't seem to work on the shape elements css3pie generates with css only. I had to modify the minified .htc file as folows :
look for the second occurance of "shape" in the script. It's in a function called 'Aa'.
After this statement:

```
g=e[a]=f.p.Za("shape");
```

you can add:

```
g.style.filter="inherit";
```

This clearly is a hack but it works great!
It is just for IE8. IE7 deals with transparency differently (http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-opacity-inheritance)