# change opacity for sub div

Tags: html, css

i have two div one big full page and sub short div in big div in dialog
i want when click dialog show show dialog whith 0.3 opacity for big and 1.0 opacity for short div . but when show dialog all div show whit 0.3 opacity . how i can set this?

code

```
<div id="incomedialog" style="width:100%;position:absolute;height:100%;min-height:overflow:hidden;background-color:#7F7F7F;display:none;opacity:0.4;" >
<div style="text-align:right;width:600px;position:absolute;left:0;right:0;height:470px;min-height:overflow:hidden;300px;background-color:#EEEEEE;border:2px solid #CDCDCD;border-radius:3px;color:white;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;top:70px;opacity:1.0;">
</div>
</div>
```

i set 0.3 opacity for big div and 1.0 opacity for sub div but not work .

Comment: the style rules in your code are invalid - it would be better if you didn't use inline styles - easier to maintain and easier to see when you've made mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `opacity` you can use **rgba** color property for this. Write like this:

```
#incomedialog{
    background-color:rgba(127,127,127,0.4);
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Q7B9x/

Check this for more [Opacity of div's background without affecting contained element in IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662178/opacity-of-divs-background-without-affecting-contained-element-in-ie-8/5662237#5662237)

Answer (score 1):

Set `z-index:100;` for the big `div`

Set `z-index:101;` for the inner `div`

Comment: @behzadn Please style your divs properly.

Comment: whats my mistake in css style?

Comment: z-index do nothing on it because the inner DIV still the child of the big DIV. So, if you give opacity to your big DIV it's effect all there children.