# IE 8 Opacity affects all child elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I have a div I want to set an opacity on. I have the following CSS:

```
background: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* IE 7 and Earlier */
/* Next 2 lines IE8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
```

Works fine in compliant browsers but in IE 8 this also makes child elements with the div transparent.

I am aware this question is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662178/opacity-of-divs-background-without-affecting-contained-element-in-ie-8) but the answers there didn't work for me.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: That is the expected functionality. Changing the opacity on an element means that anything inside of it is also affected.

Comment: I thought the RGB values would limit it to the parent element? Are you suggesting IE8 cannot limit the amount of elements affected?

Comment: @MeltingDog **Cascading** Style Sheets; if you make the parent transparent, the children will be too. Items cannot be *more* visible than the element they're in.

Comment: @MeltingDog think of it as though you've got some seats and a steering wheel inside a car. If you set the car's opacity to 50%, would you expect to see through the car completely, or expect to see the seats and the steering wheel as though the rest of the car were disappearing? That'd be a very strange effect.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 doesn't support RGBa, and the MS Filter opacity will effect the element and it's children.

Suggested fix from http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

```
<!--[if IE]>

   <style type="text/css">

   .color-block { 
       background:transparent;
       filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000); 
       zoom: 1;
    } 

    </style>

<![endif]-->
```

**OR (using conditional classes)**

```
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

   .ie8.your-selector { 
       background:transparent;
       filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000); 
       zoom: 1;
    }
```

**OR**

another way to get around this is to use a 1px by 1px transparent png that repeats as the background image for the element..

Comment: You can try the 'fix' at the bottom of the article.

Comment: Sounds good! So with the 'if' statement above, must this be on my HTML file? Is there a way I can put this if statement in my external CSS file?

Comment: Yes. If you're using HTML5boilerplate.com or conditionals on the HTML tags, you can access the ie classes through conditionals. I'll update my answer.