# css opacity stacking order

Tags: html, css

I'm try to add a white div on top of an image, then add opacity to the white layer so that I can put text over the image.

The HTML:

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="white">
        <div id="blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px
}
#red {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -15;
}
#white {
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -10;
}
#blue {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nd2EZ/1/

The background appears pink, which is great.  But the blue box I want to appear on top, in blue - but sadly it is purple.  So the blue box is a bit opaque for some reason.

How can I make the blue box appear on top, without any opacity?

Comment: It is not possible. You could use some extra markup though and put the desired content of `#white` into a sibling of `#blue` and give that element the `opacity:0.5`

Comment: [CSS Opacity That Doesn’t Affect Child Elements](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `opacity`, you can use `rgba`(Red - Green - Blue - Alpha), this will get you the desired effect..

```
#white {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    position: relative;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nd2EZ/9/)

BTW, do you really need `z-index` :-/ ?

Comment: Note that rgba values will be ignored in IE8. The same goes for opacity, but there's a more direct work around for that.

Comment: @ChrisD There are [polyfills](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) available for that

Answer (score 2):

The opacity applies to all content, including children. Imagine the children being rendered first, and then having the opacity applied to this rendered content. If the element is *not* a child - i.e. in a different hierarchy and positioned over - then it won't be affected by the opacity of the (previous) parent.

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="white">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="blue"></div>

#blue {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could could structure your HTML like this:

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

and change your css to:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px
}
#red {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
#white {
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#blue {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes you have done are by taking them as child. The opacity effects the child. When `white` opacity is `0.5` when `blue` opacity will be `0.5` even it to `1`. [More documentation is here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/).

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5662239/1097972) to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

move div#blue to be a child of div#red, and than set the css style position of div#blue to absolute;

**HTML**

```
<div id="red">
    <div id="white">
    </div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px
}
#red {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -15;
}
#white {
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -10;
}
#blue {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    position:absolute;
    left:0em;
    top:0em;
}
```