# How can I change the background colour transparency without affecting contents of a div?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation bar which I want to have a  white background for, although I only want the white to be transparent, whenever I currently change the transparency it makes the whole  transparent. How can I change my code so that only the white background is transparent?

```
  <div class="col-md-10"><div id="navigation" style="background-color:white; opacity: 0.5;"> <ul class="nav" style="margin-left: -20%;">
  <li><a href="MusicFestival.php">Home <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="Friday.php">Friday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="Saturday.php">Saturday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="Sunday.php">Sunday <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i></a>  </li>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just searched for "make div background transparent without affecting content" on google.

Here is the code sample using **RGBA**

```
.myelement {
    background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
}
```

There is already an answer to your question on StackOverflow. 
Just follow this link : [Opacity of a DIV without affecting content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662178/opacity-of-divs-background-without-affecting-contained-element-in-ie-8/5662662)

And some more tips here : [RGBa Browser Support](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)