# front end development: web browsers differences when using browserstack

Tags: css, testing, cross-browser, browserstack

- Scope: only front end issues (HTML, CSS, javascript)
- browsers/devices: desktop browsers (IE8+, Chrome, Firefox & Safari), ipad's browser (mobile Safari), mobile devices browsers (android, mobile safari)

I have experienced unexpected differences between a page rendered in IE8 locally (IE8 installed on a physical machine) & the same page rendered in IE8 in Browserstack.

This concerns the CSS properties `filter` and `-ms-filter`, more details on the comment of this answer: [Cross browser rgba transparent background while keeping content (text & images) non-transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792090/cross-browser-rgba-transparent-background-while-keeping-content-text-images/4792173#4792173)

Have you had similar experiences, if yes, how often & on what features (links please)?

Answer (score -1):

Also need to add `background: transparent\9;`
Also do check the IE8 mode.

Comment: I am not discussing a specific way of doing something here. I assume you are trying to tell me how to use transparent background in IE8.

Comment: @AdrienBe: Is your site an internal site?

E makes assumption about displaying intranet sites (http://someInternalSite/ vs. http://someInternalSite.myCompany.org). That assumption is that intranet sites work best in compatibility mode.