# How to set opacity to the background color of a div?

Tags: html, css, opacity, background-color

I have this class

```
.box { background-color:#fff; border:3px solid #eee; }
```

My question is how can I set an opacity to the white background only so that it will kinda mix with my background?

Thank you.

Comment: Just put the exact color what u need instead of white.. :)

Comment: @kvijayhari — assuming the background is a solid colour.

Comment: I dont mean that, I need to "blend" it with my white color

Comment: look at the popular http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on

Answer (score 19, accepted):

CSS 3 introduces [rgba colour](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color), and you can combine it with graphics for a [backwards compatible](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/) solution.

Comment: This is the way I always work when I have to do something with front-end code. Useful answer.

Comment: You are right.. But i dont understand the need for this .. Can u explain a bit of it.. Look at the example at http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/demo-3.html , it ok with that.. But why can't just put the background color of #7F0080 which is the semitransparent color result in that example.. Most importantly that will be supported by all browsers..

Comment: This uses a "fallback image" though, not really a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: @kvijayhari — Because the translucent element overlaps things of more then a single solid colour.

Comment: @Phil — I said you *can* combine it with graphics for backwards compatibility, you don't have to. If you want a solid colour in browsers that don't support rgba then that is also an option.

Answer (score 29):

I think [rgba](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/) is the quickest and easiest!

`background: rgba(225, 225, 225, .8)`

Answer (score 7):

I think this covers just about all of the browsers. I have used it successfully in the past.

```
#div {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;      /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;       /* mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 0.5;           /* fx, safari, opera */
}
```

Comment: That applies to the whole element, not just the background.

Comment: Yeah, that is what the OP wants.

Comment: Yea, not a totally hustle free but you can make it so that just the background opacity will be changed. @Phil cant be sure about that.. there is not mentioning if this .box has any content in it.

Comment: @Phil — the question says "to the white **background**"

Comment: @Lollero — not using `opacity`, that applies to the whole element.

Comment: @phil as i said, it does take some work but still. It is doable: http://jsfiddle.net/4tTNZ/

Comment: @Lollero, I totally agreed with you and knew it could be done.

Comment: @phil Sorry, meant to say that to @Quentin

Comment: @Quentin no? where do you base that on? Just because in my example it doesnt do something, doesnt mean that it cant do so in any situation. I did that as a proof of concept. If you add `float: left;` to the outer div, it will wrap around the text. It acts just as normal div box would, it just has extra markup.

Comment: lol am i imagining things? Where did Quentins comment go?

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS3 RGBA in this way:

```
rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
```

`0.7` means 70% opacity.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the easiest way is to use transparent background image.

http://jsfiddle.net/m48nH/

```
background: url("http://musescore.org/sites/musescore.org/files/blue-translucent.png") repeat top left;
```