# changing a parent's opacity while keeping the child's same

Tags: css

in the try it yourself page, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_opacity, they set the opacity of the div to be 60%. In doing so,
the black text also changed. Is there a way to achieve the effect of having the div transparent without modify the opacity of the text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624457/how-to-set-opacity-to-the-background-color-of-a-div/6624569#comment-7823841 Note that i do have comment there ( under Phil's answer ) showing a way to do it with css opacity, if that is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. You can make use of `rgba` values

See this - http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/jR2ZZ/

Instead of using `opacity`, use `rgba`

### HTML

```
<div>
This element's opacity is 0.5! Note that both the text and the background-color are affected by the opacity level!
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. `opacity` itself will always affect the children of the element it's on, and there's nothing you can do about it.

What you can do is give the `div` a `background-color` using `RGBa` - for instance `div { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /* 60% opaque black */ }` That will affect only the `div` it's applied to, but not children or content.

Support for RGBa isn't universal - Firefox and Chrome support it, but IE 8 and below don't, so remember to specify a fallback colour.

See [here](http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/) for more details.