# Can I set an opacity only to the background image of a div?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Let's say I have

```
<div class="myDiv">Hi there</div>
```

I want to put a `background-image` and give it an `opacity` of `0.5` – but I want that the text I have written will have full opacity (`1`).

If I would write the CSS like this

```css
.myDiv { opacity:0.5 }
```

**everything** will be in low opacity – and I don't want that.

So my question is – How can I get low-opacity background image with full opacity text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624457/how-to-set-opacity-to-the-background-color-of-a-div/6624569#comment-7823841 Note that i do have comment there ( under Phil's answer ) showing a way to do it with css opacity, if that is the preferred way.  ( http://www.jsfiddle.net/4tTNZ )

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4183985/464273) is much more succinct and I believe is exactly the same.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Nope, this cannot be done since `opacity` affects the whole element including its content and there's no way to alter this behavior. You can work around this with the two following methods.

### Secondary div

Add another `div` element to the container to hold the background. This is the most cross-browser friendly method and will work even on IE6.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    Hi there
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.myDiv {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.myDiv .bg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(test.jpg) center center;
    opacity: .4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbGb4/2/)

### :before and ::before pseudo-element

Another trick is to use the CSS 2.1 `:before` or CSS 3 `::before` pseudo-elements. `:before` pseudo-element is supported in IE from version 8, while the `::before` pseudo-element is not supported at all. This will hopefully be rectified in version 10.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    Hi there
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.myDiv {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.myDiv:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(test.jpg) center center;
    opacity: .4;
}
```

#### Additional notes

Due to the behavior of `z-index` you will have to set a z-index for the container as well as a negative `z-index` for the background image.

### Test cases

See test case on jsFiddle:

- [Using CSS 2.1 :before](http://jsfiddle.net/sbGb4/4/)
- [Using CSS 3 ::before](http://jsfiddle.net/sbGb4/3/)

Comment: I'm super paranoid when it comes to using negative values with z-index.. but, i cant argue with results. Howevveer, i would add `width: 100%; height: 100%;` to the `.bg` so that ie6 can spread the bg inside the parent div. http://jsfiddle.net/sbGb4/2/

Comment: I thought there is a css3 trick for it that I am missing - but this is great too!

Comment: @Lollero good point! `z-index` is a pain, but this should be relatively safe as long as you give the parent a positive index.

Comment: @Alon if you check that comment I wrote under your Question post. I have link there to another question that has several other options Including rgba Which is the css3 option. Heres quite good trick for older ie.. http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/

Comment: @Alon I added another method using the `::before` pseudo-element. Was this the one you were looking for?

Comment: I got this to work completely without the `z-index` or the `:before`. See answer below.

Comment: @abalter You only omitted z-index. Your answer uses the "Secondary div" method that is listed first in my answer. Trusting the browser to handle z-index (as expected) is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Finally, this is it. THANKS @mekwall

Answer (score 202):

So here is an other way:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5), rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), url("your_image.png");
```

Comment: @jj_: Because at the time there was very limited support for `linear-gradient`. The accepted answer I wrote is over 4 years old ;)

Comment: Maybe you could add a comment or a little update to your question, informing that this is now the new good way to do it. See you in 4 years for a new update ;)

Comment: @jj_: Actually, this solution doesn't make the image transparent. It only adds a white layer with 50% transparency on top of it. Hence, it's not a valid answer for the question.

Comment: I think we can agree that it achieves the intent of the question so yeah it's a valid answer for the question.

Comment: This is by far the most creative, intuitive way to solve this problem. It is also a LOT easier to use than the alternatives and provides you with more control. By allowing it to be a gradient you can make the area at the bottom lighter so the footers can be read more easily.

Comment: Not "pure" opacity in the sense, but yeah this is the best answer. So clean and simple. The accepted answer is too outdated and clumsy for 2018.

Comment: Sadly, this will not work if you need to support IE9

Comment: This solution still affects any text that is a child of the background image.

Comment: This is working on most cases. But if you have divs staked on top of each other, with let's say a 0.5 opacity you will see a white (ish) background instead of seeing the other background. White with transparency is not pure opacity. I'm still waiting for this to be solved in css for some time now.

Answer (score 9):

## css

```
div { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

div::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(image.jpg); 
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

## html

```
<div> put your div content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented [Marcus Ekwall's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7241440/188963) but was able to remove a few things to make it simpler and it still works. Maybe 2017 version of html/css?

html:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id='bg'></div>
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
    book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
    desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#content {
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/6644/sea-water-ocean-waves.jpg') center center;
  opacity: .4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/3te9fjL5/

Comment: This is doing the same as the "Secondary div" in my answer, with the only difference being that you omitted the z-index (it is possible this behaves differently today and may also depend on browser). But trusting the browser to behave as expected is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hello to everybody I did this and it worked well

```js
 var canvas, ctx;

  function init() {
   canvas = document.getElementById('color');
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

   ctx.save();
   ctx.fillStyle = '#bfbfbf'; //  #00843D   // 118846
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 490, 490);
   ctx.restore();
  }
```

```css
section{
  height: 400px;
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/265087/pexels-photo-265087.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
 
}

canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 opacity: 0.9;

}

#text {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}


.middle{
 text-align: center;
 
}

section small{
 background-color: #262626;
 padding: 12px;
 color: whitesmoke;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;

}

section i{
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
}

section h1{
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Metrics</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">  
</head>  
  
<body onload="init();">
<section>
<canvas id="color"></canvas>

<div class="w3-container middle" id="text">
<i class="material-icons w3-highway-blue" style="font-size:60px;">assessment</i>
<h1>Medimos las acciones de tus ventas y disenamos en la WEB tu Marca.</h1>
<small>Metrics &amp; WEB</small>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by using the different div class for the text Hi There...

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="bg">
   <p> Hi there</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Now you can apply the styles to the

tag. otherwise for bg class.
I am sure it works fine

Answer (score -1):

None of the solutions worked for me. If everything else fails, get the picture to Photoshop and apply some effect. 5 minutes versus so much time on this...

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style=" background-color: #00000088"> Hi there </div>
<!-- #00 would be r, 00 would be g, 00 would be b, 88 would be a. -->
</body>
</html>
```

including 4 sets of numbers would make it rgba, not cmyk, but either way would work (rgba= 00000088, cmyk= 0%, 0%, 0%, 50%)

Comment: what has this to do with opacity?