# Adjust background image opacity on bootstrap hero unit

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I edit my css to adjust the opacity on the background image in the hero unit without affecting the opacity of the text etc in the hero unit?  Here is the draft site (yes i'll be paying for proper version of the photo):  [site](http://www.clearsoftinc.com/NewSiteBasic/)

Comment: Why don't you just make it transparent in photoshop? (or something similar)

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7241440/2198378

Comment: I don't have photoshop and if grew impatient with GIMP rather quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer is to take your .jpg, and create a .png with it that has your opacity already applied.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to move your hero text outside of the hero unit and use `position:relative` to place it where you want...

### CSS

```
.hero-unit {
  background-image:url('..');
  height:300px;
  opacity: .5;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -350px;
  left: 40px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-unit">
  </div>
  <h1>Hello Hero Text</h1>  
</div>
```

<kbd>[**Demo on Bootply**](http://bootply.com/62096)</kbd>

This example assumes your hero text it contained in an H1, but it could be in any container outside of the hero.

Comment: Thanks.  The only concern I have with this is that I's be sort of breaking the standard bootstrap hero unit structure which could be risky for a css amateur like myself.  I could see myself screwing up alignments and such as the site evolves.

Answer (score 0):

The Original Post was some time ago, but I recently had the same problem, and could not get to the bottom of it, but it seems it has nothing to do with the image itself but the fact that the image it seems is classed as background-image. After a quick support call to the template supplier 'bootstrapmade.com' they pointed out that this was the adjuster.'0' being no opacity (Clear Image) and '1'  and 1 being completly obscure.
To get my head around this I found it useful to understand what 'opacity meant, "the quality of lacking transparency" So '0' Is completly lacking transparency, and '1' is complete transparency. Adjustments are made after a decimal point eg; half transparency would be '0.5'. I hope this has helped anyone with the same problem.

[image]