# setting opacity for background image with url in css

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap along with HTML5 to develop a website.
I have a website header.
I wish to have an image in the website header with some opacity value and also some text in it.
I have referred this link [setting opacity for background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241341/can-i-set-an-opacity-only-to-the-background-image-of-a-div) and tried implementing it. I have got the text but not the image.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="page-header head">
<div class="hbg"></div>
Hi there
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.head{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
margin-top:10px;
height: 170px;
}

.head .hbg
{
background: url('hbg.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
opacity: 0.3;
z-index: -1;
}
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: “What is the issue here?” Well, you should tell us…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; to .hbg and width and height of 100% so it spreads all over the parent container:)

```css
.head {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 170px;
}
.head .hbg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: url('http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png');
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header head">
  <div class="hbg"></div>
  Hi there
</div>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of width and height here? If I remove it, the image disappears. Why?

Comment: You need to add width and height on .hbg so it can fill it's parent container. The image is just a background of .hbg and plays no role in the width and height, it will spread to how big is the element that it is added as background :)

Answer (score 3):

.head .bg doesnt exist in the code above. Change to .hbg.

Comment: I have changed it. But still no effect.

Comment: The article you're referring uses
        position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
try adding that..

Answer (score 1):

How about this instead?

```
<div class="page-header head">
Hi there
</div>
```

-

```
.head{
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.head::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(hbg.png);
  opacity: 0.3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```