# How can I set a div elements background image, with 50% opacity, when image name can vary

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a foreach loop within my MVC view cycling through my model, and in it a separate div element is rendered for each object in my list. Now, I want the background of this object to be an image with 50% opacity. The image is not the same for iteration of the loop, however, and will depend on one of the parameters of the model object.

To make it clearer, currently I have:

```
@foreach (var itm in Model)
{    
    <div id="shell" style="position: relative; etc....">
       Many other div elements placed with position: absolute within the shell container.
    </div>
}
```

The name of the image within my content folder can be found by `itm.Company + jpeg`, and I want to make this the background image of the div with `opacity: 0.5;`

I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241341/can-i-set-an-opacity-only-to-the-background-image-of-a-div) that I can't merely set the background image to the shell div because then I can't change it's opacity without changing the entire div's opacity.

The following answer states I should create it by including another div like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    Hi there
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myDiv {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.myDiv .bg {
  position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(test.jpg) center center;
    opacity: .4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried this:

```
@foreach (var itm in Model)
{    
    <div id="shell" style="z-index: 1; position: relative; etc....">
        <div class="companyImage" style="z-index:-1; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background: url(~/Content/images/@(itm.Company).jpeg);">                                                                            
        </div>
        Many other div elements placed with position: absolute within the shell container.
    </div>    
}
```

However, the razor within the `url()` part of my companyImage div's style sheet doesn't render properly. I get no error, but the highlighting in VS disappears and it does nothing.

So does anyone know the best way of setting the background image of a div element, with 50% opacity, taking into account that I need to change the image name on each iteration of my foreach loop?

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/ ) of the scenario?

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/sbGb4/2/ which I credit to @MarkusEkwall is his example. And that's what I want, but I need to insert into the url the itm.Company string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your url, since you are passing the variable as a raw string, the url is literally  url(**~/Content/images/@(itm.Company).jpeg**), and not the value of your `itm.Company`. To do that you must use something in the lines of  the following code:

```
...url(~/Content/images/"+@itm.Company+".jpeg);"
```

So that `itm.Company` is interpreted as C# code.