# Child element inheriting parent's opacity

Tags: html, css

I am working on a webpage and I want to put a button on a transparent div that shows the background image. But when I place the button it is also transparent. How can I make it not transparent?

```css
div.background {
  background: url(klematis.jpg) repeat;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
div.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="transbox">
    <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.</p>
    <input type="button" value="Ok">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a style for the button itself? (You don't in the code shown.)

Comment: put opacity of 1 on the button itself, add an id or class to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `rgba()` color method instead of `opacity`:

```css
div.background {
  background: url(klematis.jpg) repeat;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
div.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="transbox">
    <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.</p>
    <input type="button" value="Ok">
  </div>
</div>
```

With [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity), the effect applies to the entire element, including child elements and content.

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):*

> [Opacity] applies to the element as a whole, including its contents,
>   even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, an
>   element and its contained children all have the same opacity relative
>   to the element's background, even if the element and its children have
>   different opacities relative to one another.

The exception to this rule is `background-color` set with `rgba()`.

The `rgba()` color model allows for the `opacity` to be set via the alpha channel.

So you could set the parent to `div { background-color: rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.6); }`, and that would set the `opacity` to `0.6` on the `background-color` alone. Child elements would be unaffected.

Learn more here: [A brief introduction to Opacity and RGBA](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/)

For opacity and images see:

- [Can I set an opacity only to the background image of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7241341/3597276)
- [CSS: set background image with opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4183948/3597276)

Comment: Thank you that is completely awesome :)