# Span not showing when input is focused

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
 .email-input-container>span{
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }



input:focus + span{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Link to complete code here:

http://codepen.io/Drew69/pen/gLgvxJ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38236688/3597276 (see section below code in this answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `<span>` after the `<input>` field.

Do:

```
<div class="email-input-container">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
  <span>Email</span>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="email-input-container">
    <span>Email</span>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @frempong69 Please accept this answer if it really helped you.

Answer (score 0):

you have given your span `opacity: 0`, so it doesn't shows up.

the + selector applies to elements after the called element. see here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

Answer (score 0):

you specified `+` which mean input and then span like this

```
 <div class="email-input-container">
         <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <span>Email</span>
    </div>
```