# Opacity on Background Images and z-index

Tags: css, background-image, z-index, opacity

I have a wrapper that is set as a background-image that I am trying to make transparent. My opacity is at 0.5. Everything that is in (or "in front of") the wrapper is now transparent as well. I realize that opacity is something that is inherited, but is there a way around this?

From what I have researched, you can get around it by using the rgba css selector if the background is set to a color...but what if the background is an image?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post HTML and CSS

Comment: No, you cannot affect the opacity of a background image. - Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements?rq=1

Comment: .... and this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4183948/3597276

Comment: ... and this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7241341/3597276

Comment: and this won't hurt either: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask