# How to change only the background image opacity?

Tags: html, css, background-image, opacity

I am trying to change the opacity of my background image to make it match the website. The problem is that the `opacity: 0.5;` change everything within the element. So not only the background image change but also the text and every other element in the section. How am i supposed to change only the color of the image? Here is my code:

```
section {
   background-image: url(../IMG/Photo_NR1.jpg);
   padding: 15px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 700px;
}
```

I have done some research but i couldn't find anything. I tried to have all my elements out of the `<section>` tag but then i was forced to change the position of the elements again. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: And you could also have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241341/can-i-set-an-opacity-only-to-the-background-image-of-a-div, if you had just typed your question title into Google verbatim ...

Comment: What am i supposed to do if my Question is marked as duplicate? Should i delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also do this by a pseudo element. Something like this:

```
section {
   position: relative;
   padding: 15px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 700px;
}

section::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .5; 
  background-image: url(../IMG/Photo_NR1.jpg);
}
```

So you do not need an image tag and you separating the design from content.

Answer (score 2):

Try to seperate the image.

Html:

```
<div class="my-container">
    <img src="your/image">
</div>
```

Css:

```
.my-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.my-container img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Source:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-change-a-css-background-images-opacity